# Keep suspended on lid closed

Tags: suspend, power-management, lid

I have a lap top with Ubuntu v22.10 Mate v1.26.0
When I close the lid it suspends, but then regularly wakes up again without opening the lid (which can lead to a very hot bag, and a drained battery)

I have so far managed to emulate this by pressing the lid hard so it presses a key, and by plugging in a usb device.

Is there a setting which says "suspend on lid close, and stay suspended **WHATEVER HAPPENS** until lid is repoened"

Comment: v22.10 is now EOL https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades